# Continuous dependence of first Dirichlet Eigen value on the domain.

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, linear-pde

Let $\Omega$ be a open, bounded domain in $R^n$. Let $Lu=\sum (a_{ij}(x)u_{x_i})_{x_j} +c(x) u$ be the operator where $a_{ij}=a_{ji}$ are in $C^1$ and $c(x)$ is continuous. Let $\Omega_0$ be a bounded open set with $C^2$ boundary, whose closure is compact in $\Omega$. Let also $\Omega_\epsilon=\{x\in\Omega : dist(x,\Omega_0)<\epsilon\}$. We need to show that $\lambda(\Omega_\epsilon)\to\lambda(\Omega_0)$ as $\epsilon\to0$. Here $\lambda(\Omega_\epsilon)$ is the first Dirichlet Eigen value of $L$ in $\Omega_\epsilon$ and $L$ is uniformly elliptic operator.

I tried with relating the first Eigen value with the Rayleigh quotient and then using the Poincare inequality but I did not succeeded to proving anything. Since the minimizer changes with domain changing I have no idea how to approach. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since you mention the Poincaré inequality, do you assume that the matrix $(a_{ij})$ is positive definite?

Comment: Ohh I forgot to mention the uniform ellipticity condition.

Comment: Anyone care to help?

Comment: The Rayleigh quotient is a good start. You can avoid the changing domain by defining the functional on $L^2(\Omega)$ and setting it $\infty$ if $u\notin H^1_0(\Omega_\epsilon)$. The inequality $\lambda(\Omega_\epsilon)\leq \lambda(\Omega_0)$ is then immediate.

Comment: I see that already. Since the minimizer change as epsilon changed I can't show the limit go to the required answer.

Comment: The sequence of minimizers is bounded in $H^2(\Omega)$ by the inequality for the eigenvalues and Garding's inequality, hence (up to subsequence) convergent in $H^1(\Omega)$. The limit is clearly in $\bigcap_{\epsilon>0} H^1_0(\Omega_\epsilon)$. You want to show that it is in $H^1_0(\Omega)$. I think that is true, but I have not worked it out. It is probably technical.

Comment: What's Garding's inequality?

Comment: Maybe that's not even the right name. I mean the elliptic regularity result that asserts $\|u\|_{H^2}\leq C(\|Lu\|_{L^2}+\|u\|_{L^2})$ for $L$ uniformly elliptic.

Answer (score 0):

The result is indeed true, and it is valid under very general settings.
As was pointed out in the comments by MaoWao, the convergence takes place provided $H^1(\Omega) = \cap_{\varepsilon>0} H_0^1(\Omega_\varepsilon)$.
And this equality is known to be true if, in particular, $\Omega$ is of class $C^2$.

See
[Babuška, I., & Výborný, R. (1965). Continuous dependence of eigenvalues on the domain. Czechoslovak Mathematical Journal, 15(2), 169-178]
and
[Fuglede, B. (1999). Continuous domain dependence of the eigenvalues of the Dirichlet Laplacian and related operators in Hilbert space. Journal of Functional Analysis, 167(1), 183-200],
for independent expositions about the convergence.